# can I Use mysql,oracle database as well as sql server on Same system

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have installed `SQL-Server 2008 r2` on my system,but now i need to install `MYSQL` too. Is it possible to install MYSQL and SQL-Server side-by-side. Does installing both SQL-Server and MYSQL on same system affect each other?

Comment: I guess that if the servers listen on different ports it will be fine.

Comment: ok.. can we set that ports while installation

Comment: @ChetanBodke You can, for both (MySQL and SQL Server). Just pay attention during the installation steps.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu id by mistakely its not done , then is it gonna affect previous one??

Comment: I think you can change the ports they listen on in their configuration files. For example, when using WAMP, you can configure mysql by editing this file `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\my.ini`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible. However you have to make sure the ports they listen to are different.By default mysql uses port 3306 and  SQL-server uses port 1433.They are both applications like any other application. With different processes, so they should run on the same machine without any conflicts. On setup just make sure you configure the ports well so that they do not use the same port, of which the system too should detect that the port is being used by another application.

Comment: ok @KevinKaburu but if by mistake port is not select while installation , then is it gonna affect previous one??

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have included the default ports, which shows by default they use different ports.

Comment: I think SQL server is actually 1433, but, within the past couple of weeks, I had occasion to install MySQL and MSSQL on the same server and there were no conflicts that needed to be resolved, no customization needed, in order for them to run together on the same machine... the two products are so vastly different, they don't really notice each other's presence.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the correction. I have edited the answer to the effects.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and clean answer to your question is Docker, i have created tutorial where MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and MongoDB are setup and running simultaneously in single CentOS system with 3GB of RAM without affecting each other:

https://adhoctuts.com/run-mulitple-databases-in-single-machine-using-docker-vagrant/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeqkCoX28qg

below is the content of docker-compose.yml file from the tutorial, but you need the other files as well (all files are in following git repository: https://github.com/mamedshahmaliyev/adhoctuts/tree/master/docker/multiple_databases). If you need MySQL and MSSQL only just delete other services from docker-compose.yml and run docker-compose up:

```
# link to tutorial: https://adhoctuts.com/run-mulitple-databases-in-single-machine-using-docker-vagrant/

version: "3.1"

networks:
  docker-network:  

services:
# https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql
  mysql_persistance: # service name
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql_p # container_name
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - /docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql # for data persistance
      - /docker/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d # put all the custom configuration files from host to container
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=AdHocTuts2019@
    ports:
      - "3309:3306" # map host port to container port
    networks:
      - docker-network
    #restart: on-failure

  mysql_no_persistance:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_np
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=AdHocTuts2019@
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    networks:
      - docker-network

# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU8-ubuntu
    container_name: mssql
    volumes:
      - /docker/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=AdHocTuts2019@
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - TZ=Asia/Baku
      - MSSQL_PID=Express
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - docker-network

# https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition
# Accept Terms of Service for Oracle Database Enterprise Edition (Proceed to Checkout). 
# Then in command line: docker login
# sqlplus sys/Oradoc_db1@ORCLDB as sysdba
  oracle:
    image: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
    container_name: oracle
    volumes:
      - /docker/oracle/data:/ORCL # host path must have 777 permission or writable by docker oracle user
    environment:
      - DB_SID=ORCLDB
      - DB_MEMORY=1GB
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
    networks:
      - docker-network

# https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - /docker/postgre/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=AdHocTuts2019@
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - docker-network

# https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4.21-xenial
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - /docker/mongo/data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=AdHocTuts2019@
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - docker-network
```